# How to configure reasonable timeout for nfs?

Tags: linux, nfs, timeout, nfs4

I have nfs mount to a directory on remote machine.
When the remote machine is down or disconnected, any command on the nounted nfs (such as: ls, or open file) is stuck.

I want it to just fail in a few seconds if the nfs dir is not available.

How can I do it?

in `/etc/fstab` I see

```
<remote-host-ip>:/path/to/origin /shared/point nfs defaults 0 0
```

When I run `mount` I see:

```
<remote-host-ip>:/path/to/origin on /shared/point type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1, rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namelen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=<my-ip>,local_loc=none,addr=<remote-ip>)
```

Comment: What do you consider a "reasonable" timeout?

Comment: @MichaelHampton less than 3 seconds...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`timeo` and `retrans` are effective only on `soft` nfs not on `hard` nfs.
Need to change the `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
<remote-host-ip>:/path/to/origin /shared/point nfs soft,timeo=30 0 0
```

`timeo` is timeout value of 30 deciseconds (3 seconds). there is also the `retrans` means how much retries to do in case of error.

then in case of server or service down, an error occurred after 9 seconds.

Comment: Are you certain that *all* the applications that use this filesystem are properly coded to handle the IO errors that a soft NFS mount will return?  If not, are you capable of accepting silent data corruption?  Are you running binaries from the NFS-mounted filesystem?  Are you prepared to handle applications crashing because of network hiccups?  Soft-mounted NFS filesystems are EVIL unless you really know what you are doing.  **Fix** the reliability issues, don't ignore them.

Comment: As Andrew said above, this is a dangerous thing to do. Make sure you understand the implications!

Comment: Why would anyone ever use deciseconds? What was the designer thinking?

Comment: Take note that `timeo` is specified in deciseconds (tenths of a second). So you need to set `timeo=number_of_seconds * 10`